# active record returning all relations of an object that are archived: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In ruby on rails, I have a users model, this user can have a potential_match as either a mentor or a mentee. These potential_matches can either be archived: true, or archived false and I cannot get this query to work for the life of me.

```
scope :potential_matches,
        -> {
          joins('LEFT JOIN potential_matches ON potential_matches.mentor_id = users.id OR potential_matches.mentee_id = users.id')
          .where('potential_matches.archived = false')
          .where('users.active = true')
        }
```

and the test that always fails is below:

```
describe '.potential_matches' do
    it 'returns only active potential matches' do
      user1 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      user2 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      user3 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      user4 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  
      pot_match1 = FactoryBot.create(:potential_match, {mentor_id: user1.id, mentee_id: user2.id})
      pot_match2 = FactoryBot.create(:potential_match, {mentor_id: user2.id, mentee_id: user1.id})
      pot_match3 = FactoryBot.create(:potential_match, {mentor_id: user3.id, mentee_id: user4.id, archived: true})
      pot_matches = User.potential_matches
      expect(pot_matches).to include(pot_match1, pot_match2)
      expect(pot_matches).not_to include(pot_match3)
    end
  end
```

what am i missing here? its driving me insane.

Comment: check values in the database table especially "potential_matches" in that check archived values are present or not.

Comment: This code does not make the least bit of sense. I'm guessing the scope is the User model so it will return a collection of User records - not potential matches. And I can't understand what it is you're trying to do that couldn't just be acheived with `PotentialMatch.where(archived: false)`. Why is this code even in the User model?

Comment: That would only make sense if it where an instance method and you where getting potential matches for a specific user. You might want to start over and explain to us what is your actually trying to acheive.

Comment: yeah. I realized the query doesnt return potential matches lol. I was tired after working for 15 hours. thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is get users without any archived matches the easiest way is by creating a subquery:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.potential_matches
    pm = PotentialMatch.arel_table
    id = arel_table[:id]
    where(
      PotentialMatch.where(
        pm[:mentor_id].eq(id).or(pm[:mentee_id].eq(id))
      ).where(archived: true).arel.exists.not
    ).where(active: true)
  end
end
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM   "users"
WHERE  NOT ( EXISTS (SELECT "potential_matches".*
                     FROM   "potential_matches"
                     WHERE  ( "potential_matches"."mentor_id" = "users"."id"
                               OR "potential_matches"."mentor_id" =
                            "users"."id" )
                            AND "potential_matches"."archived" = ?) )
       AND "users"."active" = ? /* loading for inspect */
LIMIT  ?
```